# Missing setup/installation files when publishing a .NET Core WPF application via ClickOnce

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.1

After porting an existing DNF 4.6.1 WPF application to .NET Core 3.1, the setup/installation files are missing after the "successful" publish of the .NET Core app. Only the built project is published. The install- and publish location are still the same file shares. This is the used publish configuration:

[image: Publish Config]

When publishing a new (empty) .NET Core 3.1 WPF application, everything works correctly (the installtion/application files are there).

Here's what we have tried so far: We created a new .NET Core WPF application and moved the code from the existing project to the new one. Just to make sure, that this has nothing to do with the .csproj-file. This still doesn't resolve the issue.

Has anyone experienced the same behavior when porting an existing DNF application to DNC?

Comment: Which files are missing and where are they missing from? Local publish folder? Remote file system? Hidden by web server?

Comment: @CorentinPane The "Application Files" directory, the setup.exe and "myproject.application"-file are missing. They are missing from a UNC file share drive.

Comment: Do they miss if you publish to a local folder instead?

Comment: @CorentinPane Yes, they also miss when being published to a local folder. As I said, a new/empty .NET Core WPF app can be successfully deployed.

Comment: Try to look for any differences in the `csproj` files. Maybe there are some properties you have to set.

Comment: @mu88 That's why I created a new project. The properties are identical.

Comment: Then we need some code to help you, I guess...

Comment: There're know issues with ClickOnce in WPF for .NET Core/5, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3898). I personably [wouldn't keep high hopes](https://dev.to/noseratio/the-signs-of-wpf-currently-being-on-life-support-1h3a) for a proper fix.